# Is it true, in an effort to do 'tagged templates', that I cannot pass a variable that returns a template literal as an argument?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```js
hero = "batman";
sidekick = "robin";
villain = "the joker"

function f(strings, good, helper, bad) {
    console.log(strings); //expected: " and must team up to defeat "
    console.log(good); //expect: "batman"
    console.log(helper);//expect: "robin"
    console.log(bad);//expect: "the joker"
}

f`${hero} and ${sidekick} must team up to defeat ${villain}`;
```

However when I store the template literal in a variable and try to pass the variable to the function it does not work:

```js
hero = "batman";
sidekick = "robin";
villain = "the joker"

sentence = `${hero} and ${sidekick} must team up to defeat ${villain}`;

function f(strings, good, helper, bad) {
    console.log(strings); //expected: " and must team up to defeat "
    console.log(good); //expect: "batman"
    console.log(helper);//expect: "robin"
    console.log(bad);//expect: "the joker"
}

fsentence;
```

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Why do you need this? `sentence` is just a string. You can't defer it's evaluation for later to use.

Comment: Template literals are evaluated when encountered. You can't just "store" an unprocessed template literal in a variable. You can make a function when called will evaluate the template literal - that's the closest you can really get to.

Comment: @VLAZ Okay, thanks

Comment: You can do ``const sentence = (t) => t`${hero} and ${sidekick} must team up to defeat ${villain}`;`` and then call `sentence(f)` but it's rather weird to pass in the tag function. Normally you'd pass the substitution values